# Mostar el último registro por cada código filtrando entre fechas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

cordial saludo, espero me puedan ayudar.
Tengo una tabla en sql server llamada producto que tiene los siguientes campos(**id**,**codigo**,**nombre**,**fecha**,**cantidad**,**habia**,**saldo_final**), en el campo (habia) registro la cantidad de cada producto, en el campo (saldo_final) es lo que queda cuándo sale un producto.
Este tipo de consulta es la que estaba haciendo, mostrando el saldo anterior en una columna (habia)

[image: Contenido tabla productos]

Ahora me han pedido que el saldo anterior (habia) salga en una fila por cada código. Me explico gráficamente.

[image: Ejemplo resultado consulta requerida]

Sería este tipo de consulta en que el saldo anterior salta al inicio de cada codigo. Ahora como ya tengo el saldo anterior (habia) que se registra cuando sale un producto seria sacar el último registro menor a la fecha consultada.

Encontré esta consulta que me hace lo que quiero pero me saca más de 2 registros del saldo anterior(habia) por código, y solo quiero una sola fila del saldo anterior(habia) por cada código.

```
declare @Fecha1 varchar(50)
declare @Fecha2 varchar(50)
set @Fecha1 = '04/07/2021'
set @Fecha2 = '07/07/2021'
SELECT    m.codigo,m.nombre,m.fecha,m.cantidad,m.Saldo_final
FROM(
SELECT 0 as orden, p.codigo,'Sando anterior' as nombre,p.fecha,0 as cantidad,p.habia as Saldo_final
from producto as p where p.fecha < @Fecha1
UNION
SELECT 1 as orden, p.codigo,p.nombre, p.fecha, p.cantidad, p.habia as Saldo_final
from producto as p WHERE p.fecha BETWEEN @Fecha1 AND @Fecha2) m
order by m.codigo,orden;
```

Obtengo este tipo de resultado

[image: Resultado obtenido]

Solo quiero un solo saldo anterior(habia) por codigo.

Espero que me puedan ayudar. No sé si la consulta que tengo va por buen camino a habrá otra manera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Antes que nada**: Si bien se puede resolver, hay que decir que esto es un típico requerimiento para una vista y no para la base de datos.

Si numeramos las filas de forma adecuada, siendo el primer registro de cada producto ordenado por fecha el primer elemento, solo se trataría de repetir esta fila al comienzo de cada grupo/producto. Puedes usar una [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) aunque podría ser tambien una tabla temporal o una subconsulta:

```
;WITH CTE (
    SELECT codigo,
           nombre
           fecha,
           cantidad,
           habia,
           saldo_final,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY codigo ORDER BY fecha AS) as RN
           from producto 
           where fecha < @Fecha1
)
SELECT codigo,
       'Saldo anterior' as 'nombre',
       NULL,            as 'fecha',
       0                as 'cantidad',
       habia            as 'saldo_final',
       0                as 'RN'
       FROM CTE
       WHERE RN = 1

UNION

SELECT codigo,
       nombre,
       fecha,
       cantidad,
       saldo_final
       FROM CTE
       ORDER BY codigo, RN
```

Lo esencial es:

- `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY codigo ORDER BY fecha AS) as RN` que genera un numerador que se reinicia con cada producto y cuyo orden es la fecha ascendente
- Usamos la [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), para repetir la fila 1
- Ordenar de acuerdo al código y al numerador.

Comment: muchas gracia es exactamente lo que estaba buscando